# How would I get a different message on each screen?

Tags: vee-validate

I'm battling with Vee Validate 3.0 and am beginning to wonder if it's worth continuing with. All I want to do is create a custom message for a specific field on a specific page.

I've tried the code below to change the regex message but I can't get it to work.

I'm using Vee Validate 3.0 with Vue, so there aren't many resources online to help. Version 2 syntax seems to be a lot simpler!

```
<ValidationObserver ref="observer" v-slot="{ invalid }" tag="form" @submit.prevent="submit()">
  <ValidationProvider :rules="{ regex: /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}$/ }" name="exp_date" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input name="exp_date" v-model="payment.expdate" placeholder="Expiry MM/YYYY" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="warning">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
   </ValidationProvider>
</ValidationObserver>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate'

export default {
  components: {
    ValidationProvider,
    ValidationObserver
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      customMessages: {
        en: {
          fields: {
            'exp_date': {
              regex: 'The date format is MM/YYYY'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Update

I've got somewhere with this but I'm not sure if I'm setting things up correctly.

In my main.js I am importing vee-validate.js like this

```
import './vee-validate'
```

In vee-validate.js I'm setting up everything I need for validation at the application level like this

```
import { extend, configure, localize } from 'vee-validate'
import { required, max, max_value, email, regex, is, is_not } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import en from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en.json'

// Install rules
extend('required', required)
extend('max', max)
extend('max_value', max_value)
extend('email', email)
extend('regex', regex)
extend('is', is)
extend('is_not', is_not)

// Override English
localize({
  en: {
    messages: en.messages,
    fields: {
      exp_date: {
        regex: '{_field_} is the wrong format. MM/YYYY'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now, setting the custom message here is working for me but what I don't understand is, if I have the same field on 2 separate screens, how would I get a different message on each screen?

### Update 2

I don't think there's a way to set up a message per page - I think the way around this is to ensure each page has unique field names.

Comment: Could you describe what is happening with your example at this time? Do you get an error or just no validation?

Comment: @Merc, The validation does fire, but I still see the default message rather than my custom one

Comment: Hm I used vee-validate with custom messages and custom validators, but I think it was with vee-validate 2. So with 3 a few things may have changed. I will try to have a look at the new version, but in the meantime: I used it like this `import validationMessagesEn from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en'` and then I would add custom messages like `validationMessagesEn.messages.atLeastOne =
  'At least one interest has to be selected.'` which I would use later on in a custom validator...
Anyway I will try to have a look at it

Comment: Ok I see. Of course if you set your message for one validation it will be used in your whole app. I think, as you said yourself, there is no way to change the message for pages per se. Maybe you could change the message depending on the route? (Do you have access to the route somewhere in your code where you define the message?)

Comment: Other than that: How do you use vee-validate. on a component level? (here they register it globally: https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/getting-started.html#es6). but maybe you don't have to register it globally, but just use in your two pages/components, and extend the messages on each with the specific message? Would that work?..
Sorry other than that I would have to install vee-validate in a vue app and test myself...

Comment: @Merc - I think you can register it at the page level, but I was just wondering if I was missing something, and there was a way to register globally and have a per page message. There's probably not much of a use case for it though - a password is a password after all, so you'd probably always want to use the same message, and for the odd time you don't you'd just have to use a different field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can do that, by either calling `localize` yourself on each page or using the `ValidationProvider`'s `customMessages` prop.

**First Method:** You could call `localize` in each page's component `created` or `mounted` lifecycle methods:

```
<template>
  <!-- Your Template -->
</template>

<script>
import { localize } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  mounted () {
    localize('en', {
      // custom messages for this page
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

**Second Method (recommended):** The `ValidationProvider` accepts a `customMessages` prop which can override any messages set to that field, so you could have a per-page setup like this:

```
<template>
  <ValidationProvider :customMessages="messages" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <!-- Your Input -->
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    messages: {
      // your custom messages.
    }
  })
};
</script>
```

I'm aware the docs needs work, I'm in the process of re-writing it at the moment and hopefully, some of the unused features could get some spotlight.

Comment: Method 2 looks like a winner :)